# Best Practice for logging Kubernetes LoadBalancer IPs interactions

Tags: kubernetes, ip, load-balancing, digital-ocean

I have setup a Kubernetes Cluster on DigitalOcean with a LoadBalancer that is running my web-site application. Now I am wondering about the best practice to capture IP client (the visitor of the website) and its interactions with the website.

I stumbled upon some literature of course, both from DigitalOcean, [Get client source IP with Kubernetes Load Balancer service](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/get-client-source-ip-with-kubernetes-load-balancer-service), and from the official Kubernetes' documentation, [Logging](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/).

If I am not mistaken, a 'good' solution would be to setup an `nginx` Ingress that forwards the client IP to the LoadBalancer (as suggested in the DigitalOcean forum), and to deploy a container engine inside the cluster that will fetch logs from the cluster and provisioning it to a third entity: a backend, ELK, etc...

Is this architecture a good one? Are there detailed tutorials regarding how to fetch IPs interactions within a LoadBalancer?

Comment: have you read that: https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/kubernetes/how-to/configure-load-balancers/#external-traffic-policies-and-health-checks ?

Comment: Yeah, and I should set up the proxy protocol. What I am asking is: which one is the best approach for web analytics up to today, since even that guide is of May 2019.

Comment: Did you try setting externalTrafficPolicy to Local on LoadBalancer?

Comment: @VasiliAngapov I probably posed my question wrongly. I am asking which one is the best practice to get the IP. And yes, according to their guide it would be to set up the proxy protocol setting externalTrafficPolicy: "Local"

Comment: Proxy protocol has nothing to do with "externalTrafficPolicy: Local". externalTrafficPolicy just simply preserves the client IP without using proxy protocol.

Comment: Aha! Just another question. How would you forward it to the frontend? I am running a React/Nodejs application. I read about forwarding, but couldn't figure out exactly how React should see it

Comment: Forward what? How should React see what?

Comment: The client IP. Setting the policy to externalTrafficPolicy (as you say) preserves the IP of the client. How then do I forward it to my frontend that is running in the same cluster/load-balancer?

Comment: You expose your frontend as Kubernetes Service with type of LoadBalancer, is that right or not? After that when client hits the load balancer the traffic goes to your frontend app. Then your app just simply sees the client IP, that's all.